# incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[50]' from type 'char *'

Tags: c, list, hyperlink, crash

I am trying to create a link list. I have a function that deletes (delete function)  stuff from my link list. But it seems to crash when I try to compare strings. It works up until the last random printf statement.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct node {
    char data[50];
    struct node *next;
}*head;

int main()
{
    //creates a sudo user interface
    printf("1. Insert\n");
    printf("2. Display\n");
    printf("3  Count\n");
    printf("4. Delete\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n");

    //create the portion that decides the user input
    int userSelection = 0 ;
    scanf("%d", &userSelection);
    userSelect(userSelection);


    return 0;
}
//this function will handle user imput
void userSelect(int num)
{
    if(num == 1)
    {
        printf("What is your name?\n");
        char userName[30];
        scanf(" %s", userName);
        add(userName);

    } else if(num ==2) {
        display();

    } else if (num ==2){
        //do something
    } else if (num ==3){
        printf("%d", count());
        main();
    } else if (num ==4 ){
        char delName[50];
        printf("Who do you want to remove?\n");
        scanf("%s", delName);
        delete(delName);
    }else if (num == 5){
        // return 0;
    }else if (num > 6){
        printf("\n52Please make sure you use a valid option!\n\n");
        main();
    }


}

void add( char userName[] )
{
    struct node *temp;

    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    strcpy(temp->data, userName);

    if (head== NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
    printf("\n");
    main();
}
int count()
{
    struct node *n;
    int c=0;
    n=head;
    while(n!=NULL)
    {
        n=n->next;
        c++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return c;
}
void display(struct node *r)
{
    r=head;
    if(r==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    while(r!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ",r->data);
        r=r->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    main();
}


void delete(char delName)
{
    struct node *temp, *prev;
    temp=head;
    printf("sffs\n");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("sdg\n");
        if(strcmp(temp->data, delName)==0)
        {
            if(temp==head)
            {
                head=temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next=temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            prev=temp;
            temp= temp->next;
        }
    }
    main();
}
```

I think it has something to do with the strcmp in the delete function..but does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You should post the rest of your code.  You have a `free` and we don't see where it's being allocated.  Also, are you calling `main`?  That can't be right...

Comment: Is `delName` really a `char` or is it a `char *`?  You should compile with all warnings on (`gcc -Wall` if you are using gcc).

Comment: i called main just to purpose the menu again once the user completes a task, it goes back and prompts them again.

Comment: I made delName a pointer and it does not crash. Now I cant get it to call main and reopen the menu so I can check to see if it really is deleted :O

Comment: are you calling `main()` from `delete()`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that this:

```
void delete(char delName)
```

should be this:

```
void delete(char *delName)
```

However, there are many other problems with your program and it would take a long time to list all of them.  I'll just give you two things to fix:

1. You should turn on warnings and fix all of them.
2. Your functions shouldn't call `main()`.  Instead, `main()` should contain a loop, like this:

   ```
   //create the portion that decides the user input
   int userSelection = 0 ;
   do {
       scanf("%d", &userSelection);
       userSelect(userSelection);
   } while (userSelection != 5);
   ```

Comment: The function `delete` is also hard to follow since the conditionals all `return` yet continue with `else` statements. The instruction `temp= temp->next;` should be unconditional as it is essential for the loop to continue.

Comment: ok thanks! Ill replace that main() issue. So calling main in any function is a no no.